# Bash replace line if another line exist

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

Im trying to write a bash script that will read whole file line by line, look for specific line, if that line exist - extract string from it into variable and search for another specific line and replace it with this variable. It has to be in while loop as there can be multiple occurances of these pair of lines hence I do not want to replace all lines with 1 variable as every case will be different, here is an example:

```sh
line1
mynumber: 666
line3
line4
show (value)
line5
line6
mynumber: 111
line7
line8
line9
line10
show (value)
```

so I want it to look like this after replacement:

```sh
line1
mynumber: 666
line3
line4
show (666,value)
line5
line6
mynumber: 111
line7
line8
line9
line10
show (111,value)
```

here is my broken code, that fails because variables are being picked up but added 1 after another (array) and I think this is breaking sed.

```sh
 for i in $(seq $count);
 do while IFS= read -r line;
 do var1="$(grep -o -E '.{0,0}mynumber: .{0,3}' File.cs | egrep -o ".{3}$")" ; done < "$input";
sed -i "s/(value)/(${var1},value)/g
" File.cs; ; done
```

Issues im getting: Var= 666 111 and I would like to be only 1 value per replacement
and Im getting error from sed:
sed -e expression #1 : unterminated `s' command

Comment: You can do it in `sed` and it's relatively easy with hold space - put the number in hold space, then when "show" add it to pattern space - but it will be way easier with awk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AWK can do that single-handedly.

```
$ awk '$1=="mynumber:"{c=$2} $1=="show"{sub(/\(/,"&"c",")}1' file
line1
mynumber: 666
line3
line4
show (666,value)
line5
line6
mynumber: 111
line7
line8
line9
line10
show (111,value)
```

Comment: awk looks like the simplest solution, I don't want to blindly copy/paste command so is there a chance you can explain how substitution is happening here, please?

Comment: Well it's really simple, if the first word of a line is `mynumber:`, it assigns the next word to a variable named `c`, and if the first word is `show`, it **sub**stitutes the first paren on the line with a paren followed by `c` and a comma

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Your awk 1 line solution works best for me, out of all suggested solutions here. Also thank you for explaining it too.

Comment: Solve my problem with this help. thanks @oguz ismail and novak 100.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & parallel):

```
parallel -q sed -Ei '/{}/{h;:a;n;/^show/!ba;G;s/\((.*)\n.* (.*)/(\2,\1/}' file ::: 666 111
```

Use parallel to loop through the numbers `666` and `111` and sed to insert then numbers in the following `show` lines.

N.B. the numbers to be replace could be stored in a file and the same solution used with the following amended solution.

```
parallel -q sed -Ei '/{}/{h;:a;n;/^show/!ba;G;s/\((.*)\n.* (.*)/(\2,\1/}' file :::: fileContainingNumbers
```

Answer (score -1):

Perl solution:

`perl -pe '$n=$1 if /mynumber: (\d+)/; s/show \(/show($n,/' file`

Use `-p` to loop over the input file line by line. (like sed or awk)

Set `$n` to the first match group in `/mynumber: (\d+)/` if there is a match.

Then, use `s///` replacement to insert `"$n,"` after `"show("`